# Fastlane gym exportOptionsPlist error for key "iCloudContainerEnvironment": expected one of {Development, Production}

Tags: xcode, fastlane, fastlane-gym

I'm using [Fastlane](https://docs.fastlane.tools/) and [Gym](http://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/gym/#gym) to build a react-native application and when the provisioning profile is set to `ad-hoc` I get the following error:

> Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "exportOptionsPlist error for key "iCloudContainerEnvironment": expected one of {Development, Production}, but no value was provided" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=exportOptionsPlist error for key "iCloudContainerEnvironment": expected one of {Development, Production}, but no value was provided}
>
> ** EXPORT FAILED **
> [12:21:16]: Exit status: 70

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple different solutions I've tried which haven't worked, but the following finally fixed the issue:

In the `Fastfile` I replaced:

```rb
gym(export_method: "ad-hoc")
```

with the following:

```rb
gym(
  export_method: "ad-hoc",
  export_options: {
    iCloudContainerEnvironment: "Production"
  }
)
```